# Changing Image red text to black and black background to white

Tags: java, image-processing, graphics, bufferedimage

I'm trying to edit the attached image by making the red image text black and the black background white.

I have attached the below code trying to achieve the results but the new image is coming out with white text and black background.

Please assist!

IMAGE:
[image: nice image]

```
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class BlackAndWhiteTest {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    File file = new File("C://picw//screenshot.png");
    BufferedImage orginalImage = ImageIO.read(file);

    BufferedImage blackAndWhiteImg = new BufferedImage(
        orginalImage.getWidth(), orginalImage.getHeight(),
        BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_BINARY);
    
Graphics2D graphics = blackAndWhiteImg.createGraphics();
graphics.drawImage(orginalImage, 0, 0, null);

    ImageIO.write(blackAndWhiteImg, "png", new File("C://picw//newscreenshot.png")); 
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may convert blackAndWhiteImg to negative I guess.

```
for (int x = 0; x < blackAndWhiteImg.getWidth(); x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < blackAndWhiteImg.getHeight(); y++) {
            int rgba = blackAndWhiteImg.getRGB(x, y);
            Color col = new Color(rgba, true);
            col = new Color(255 - col.getRed(),
                            255 - col.getGreen(),
                            255 - col.getBlue());
            blackAndWhiteImg.setRGB(x, y, col.getRGB());
        }
    }
```